# What do you think about a tag for meta discussion about the state of the profession?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I was searching for a tag earlier to add to my question here:

[What happens if a major bug is discovered in a bioinformatic package that has been used in published literature?](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/2835/what-happens-if-a-major-bug-is-discovered-in-a-bioinformatic-package-that-has-be)

I wasn't really able to find anything appropriate, the closest that was suggested was *software-quality*.
It seems to me that this stack exchange is very much *implementation driven* - i.e. it's more closely related to programming / software specifically.

The most common questions seem to be of the general format *"How do I do X"*, *"What's the most efficient way to do Y"* etc, with the most popular tags being (predictably): [R](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r), [rna-seq](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rna-seq)
 and [python](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python)

I'd be hesistant to suggest the tag "meta" given it's implication on stackexchange generally, but I'm not sure what else / if anything would be appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe just [discussion](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion).

Having said that, this site is really not intended for open-ended questions where there's going to be debate back and forth. The whole stackexchange network is really intended to be Q&A only. As your question regarding bugs shows, sometimes more open-ended questions can be shoe-horned into quite nicely fitting the site's structure. Other times I foresee them just getting closed, which, while understandable, is nonetheless often unfortunate.

Comment: You're probably right. I do think even though it's not intended to be for open ended discussion, often questions will provoke such a thing and it will be fleshed out over answers and responses. Perhaps I just need to think more carefully about how to word a question specifically to provoke a discussion I'm interested in.